# Is there any way to change mode for vue router in vuepress

Tags: vuepress

Currently the property `mode` of vue router in vuepress is 'history'

I want to change the property `mode` of vue router in vuepress to `hash`

Is there any way to achieve this?

I tried that I created a file `enhanceApp.js` like bellow in `.vuepress` directory ( https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/basic-config.html#app-level-enhancements )

```
export default ({
  Vue, // the version of Vue being used in the VuePress app
  options, // the options for the root Vue instance
  router, // the router instance for the app
  siteData, // site metadata
  isServer // is this enhancement applied in server-rendering or client
}) => {
  router.mode = 'hash';


}
```

But there is no luck.

Comment: Why do want change `mode` of VueRouter in Vuepress? I think that isn't possible, because with `mode: 'hash'` you can't prerender of routers.

Comment: I do want to change mode of VueRouter in Vuepres because I want to use hash mode.
There is a history why do i want to use hash mode of VueRouter. I can't explain all of it.
So, isn't there any possible way to change mode of vuerouter in vuepress at all? @GabrielWillemann

Comment: I think that is not possible. But you can create a Vue app with VueRouter and [Markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it).

Answer (score 2):

```js
// .vuepress\enhanceApp.js

import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

export default ({Vue, options, router, siteData
}) => {
  router = new VueRouter({
    ...router.options,
    mode: 'hash',
  })
}
```